# Codable: give a default value to a new non-optional property

Tags: swift

If we encoded objects of a Class that conforms to `Codable` and would like to decode these objects using a new class code that has a new property, what code would be required to make that new property non-optional, and give it property a default value?

**Old class:**

```
class Item: Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

**New class:**

```
class Item: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}
```

When decoding objects saved in the old format using the new format's code, no `title` property will be found, and decoding will not work.

We could fix that by making `title` an optional `String?`.

But how would we achieve keeping `title` as a non-optional `String`, and giving it a default value when decoding each object?

PS: This is the full code. No Coding Keys were specified, and no custom init from decoder written.

Comment: You have to implement CodingKeys and `init(from decoder` with `decodeIfPresent`. The protocol extension synthesizes (aka requires) each available property.

Comment: Why would you want to store a value that will always be the same default value. Just display it to the user when reading those values and leave it nil.

Comment: @LeoDabus The default value will only be applied to decoded objects that were encoded using the old format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement required init and give it a default value:

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    let title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title) ?? "Default title"
    self.title = title

    let baseDecoder = try container.superDecoder(forKey: .id)

    try super.init(from: baseDecoder)
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps replace that whole `if let`-`else` statement with `nil`-coalescing operator: `title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title) ?? "Default title"`.

Comment: @andesta.erfan thanks! I had tried that, unsuccessfully. Can this custom init be added later on, when implementing the new format, or should it be present when the first format is implemented?

Comment: @andesta.erfan And should we edit your answer to include a decoding line for the "id" property, or is that line not needed?

Comment: @Kqtr see the edited answer

Comment: @andesta.erfan this is really interesting, and I couldn't fin it in other SO threads. Thank you for your time!